# Account unlinked after trying to add Google account as auth?

Tags: support, login

This is my Stack Overflow account: https://stackoverflow.com/users/519348/tzhx

Until just now, it was linked to my other Stack Exchange accounts.

I wanted to add Google authentication as an additional, because it had just been based on Steam's openid up to now (well, after myopenid disappeared)

Something's gone wrong though. When I try and log in with that Google account now it says it wants to create a new account, and it seems to have removed Steam auth from that site as well (logging in via Steam also prompts a "confirm and create new account" page)

I've tried in new incognito windows, etc.

I am an idiot. Can anyone help me?

Comment: Lemme see what happened here... One moment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Give it a go now, should be all set.

The short version of what went wrong here is ¯\_(ツ)_/¯.

The long version is that you did have two network accounts. When someone attempts to log in or add a credential, we try to look up whether another account exists with the same credential and merge them behind the scenes if so. In your case, we detected this exact situation, but *at some point* in the past *something* went out of sync *somewhere* and your SO profile had one account ID set while a table in the database we use to track network-wide stuff had a different account ID. Cue an exception in our logs and a really weird experience for you. Sorry about that.

I merged the two accounts, so everything should be in the right place now, but you might want to review the login credentials on your account (from your profile, "Edit Profile & Settings", then "My Logins") and remove the ones you no longer wish to have associated with your profile.

Lemme know if anything's still wonky.

Comment: Thank you! It seems to work now. :)